# How to catch exception from every method of a class in Python?

Tags: python, methods, error-handling, decorator

I am writing code which utilizes a third-party library which I do not have access to modify. To interface with the library I have written a protocol "Stub" class as follows to allow code completion in my IDE (PyCharm).

```
class Stub(Protocol):
    def x(self): ...
    def y(self): ...
```

I then have a class which makes use of the stubs to invoke methods from the third party library.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, obj: Stub):
        self._obj = obj

    def method_1(self):
        self._obj.x()

    def method_2(self):
        self._obj.y()
```

My problem is that during runtime, if the application the third party library interfaces with is closed, calling a method like `self._obj.x()` will fail with a `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` since `self._obj` is now `None`. I would like to catch these errors on any method of `MyClass` that calls a method of `self._obj` so I can raise my own more informative custom exception, but I'm not sure how I can accomplish this without wrapping every method call to `self._obj` in a `try/except` block. I thought there might be a way to decorate the class method but haven't been able to achieve this. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
import functools

def catch_except(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def function(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            print 'Exception in: ', f.__name__
    return function

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

    @catch_except
    def some_method():
        return self.num / 0

t = Test(3)
t.calc()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class decorator and it will catch exceptions from all methods inside the class.

```
def catch_exceptions(cls):  # decorator for catching all exceptions from functions inside the class
    class CatchExceptionClass:
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.ins = cls(*args, **kwargs)

        def __getattribute__(self, name):
            try:
                x = super().__getattribute__(name)
                return x
            except AttributeError:
                pass

            origin_attr = self.ins.__getattribute__(name)
            if callable(origin_attr):
                def method(*args, **kwargs):
                    try:
                        return origin_attr(*args, **kwargs)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(f"An exception caught in {cls.__name__}.{name}: {e}")
                return method
            else:
                return origin_attr

    return CatchExceptionClass


@catch_exceptions
class TestClass:
    def method_1(self):
        print("Method-1 executed")
        raise ValueError("An error occurred in method_1")

    def method_2(self):
        print("Method-2 executed")
        return 1 / 0  # Will raise ZeroDivisionError


obj = TestClass()
obj.method_1()
obj.method_2()
```